# User authorization failed xmpp in ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have registered my admin user in ejabberd. When i try to registered new user in ejabberd with xmpp php code i am getting an error `xmlrpc: Error -118 A problem '{error,access_rules_unauthorized}' occurred executing the command register with arguments`.I have tried many things but couldn't get any solution and getting the same error again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it may result tricky to configure permissions correctly for those API frontends, and get the auth details properly passed to them.

With a configuration like this:

```
listen:
  ...
  -
    port: 4560
    module: ejabberd_xmlrpc

acl:
  admin:
    user:
      - user1@localhost

api_permissions:
  "register command":
    from: ejabberd_xmlrpc
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          acl: admin
    what: register
```

And using that Python client:

```
import xmlrpclib

server_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:4560'
server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(server_url)

EJABBERD_XMLRPC_LOGIN = {'user':'user1', 'server':'localhost', 'password':'mypass11', 'admin':True}

def ejabberdctl(command, data):
    fn = getattr(server, command)
    return fn(EJABBERD_XMLRPC_LOGIN, data)

print ""
print "Calling with auth details..."
result = ejabberdctl('register', {'user':'User5', 'host':'localhost', 'password':'newpass'})
print "Results: "
print result
```

Remember to register user1 with that password, or modify that script accordingly to your admin account.

Then execute it, and should work correctly:

```
$ python test.py 

Calling with auth details...
Results: 
{'res': 0, 'text': 'User User5@localhost successfully registered'}
```